# Squash commit option is disabled on visual studio community

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-squash

I created a simple folder with a file and performed few commits for practicing squash. I selected two commits and right click. However, the squash commit option is disabled.
Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are the 2 commits consecutive?

Comment: @ElpieKay yes. they are consecutive.

Comment: same problem, did you find the answer?

Comment: I sometimes notice that when you close the Git window, and re-open it it suddenly works. It looks like when you change branches in the window it gets confused (vs2022 17.8.3)